# MSAccess - Conditional Formatting in Adjacent Rows

Tags: ms-access, conditional-formatting

I am trying the add conditional formatting to an MSAccess datasheet.  I want to highlight the following condition:

```
Number  Description
======  ==============
1111    Same Desc
1111    Same Desc
2222    Different Desc 1
2222    Different Desc 2
2222    Different Desc 3
```

For adjacent rows, where Number matches, compare the adjacent Descriptions (Note:  datasheet will be sorted by Number & Description when presented to the user in a subform):

When descriptions match, then do nothing.  When descriptions mismatch, then highlight the Description

In the example above, I'd like to highlight all 3 rows for number 2222.

I can get this to work in XLS using AND and OR formulas.  Not sure how to accomplish in MSAccess.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: instead "adjacent rows" you mean highlight only unique items? can't you concatenate the [number] & [Description] and run highlight unique fields condition?

Comment: Thanks Krish - I still need to ultimately compare descriptions in adjacent rows for each group of "Numbers" to highlight when there is some variance.

Comment: if you only want to format adjacent rows, how comes you would like to highlight all 3 rows for number 2222? that is against adjacent rule? at least in datasheet view context.

Comment: The purpose of highlighting is to indicate the adjacent descriptions within a group of "Numbers" do not MATCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, essentially:

Compare the qty (DCount) of rows containing the current "Number" alone to the number of rows containing current "Number" and "Desc".  If qty of rows of "Number" > qty rows of "Number & Desc", then there is some variation in Desc - then apply a highlight.

Conditional formatting criteria:

```
 DCount("[Number]","myTable","[Number] = '" & [Number] & "'") > DCount("[Number]","myTable","[Number] = '" & [Number] & "'And [Desc] = '" & [Desc] & "'")
```

Provides exactly what I need.

Yay